# selenium webdriver code for java drag and drop

Tags: jsp, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to selenium webdriver testing, I am doing testing for jsp code and there is one functionality to drag and drop the element. How can I write a script to do so, please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is drag and drop code of selenium webdriver:

```
 WebElement source  =  driver.findElement(By.id("Source ElementID"));
 WebElement destination  =  driver.findElement(By.id("Taget ElementID"));

 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 builder.dragAndDrop(source, destination ).perform();
```